# Calcular media de una variable categorica izquierda-dercha en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Hace muy poco que estoy utilizando R y tengo una duda (tal vez muy simple) pero no consigo solucionar de ningún modo.

Estoy analizando datos de una encuesta política, y quiero conocer la media de todos los entrevistados en un eje izquierda-derecha.

Los datos son los siguientes:

```
eje = c("Extrema izquierda", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Extrema derecha")
frec = c(2169,1181,3572,5396,4258,9664,1471,918,569,119,304)
```

He modificado los nombres de los valores de la variable "eje" por números del 0 al 10, pero no se qué comando utilizar para que R me calcule la media relacionando las dos variables (que entienda que la frecuencia de personas que han respondido "0" es 2169 personas, que las personas que han respondido "1" es de 1181, la de "2" 3572 personas, etc.).

Alguien sabe como puedo calcular esa media de algún modo rápido?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido marisantpere a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que queres saber la media de la posición política de tus participantes. En ese caso el cálculo sería el siguiente:

```
 eje <- as.numeric(c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
 frec <- c(2169,1181,3572,5396,4258,9664,1471,918,569,119,304)

 media <- sum(eje*frec)/sum(frec)
 media

 # 3.8411
```

Otra opción

```
 mean(rep(eje, frec))

 # 3.8411
```

Answer (score 1):

`R` trae la función `weighted.mean`, para obtener medias ponderadas. En tu caso el ponderador es el vector `frecuencia` y los valores el vector `eje`.

```
weighted.mean(x = eje, 
              w = frec)  #El argumento w son los pesos o ponderadores, debe ser del mismo largo que x
```

Sirve también para calcular medias en datos de encuestas que aplican un factor de ponderación simple.